# Is there a smart dynamic way to coalesce text together which is splited in to multipile rows?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I have a table structure like this:

**First table**

```
ID   | Text
----------------------
342  | Sampl    <--
342  | e Text.. <-- 
343  | Lorem ipsum
344  | Pellentesque habitant
```

**Second table**

```
ID   | lineNumb 
----------------------
342  | 1
342  | 2
343  | 1
344  | 1
```

The text is splittend by multiple rows. The ID identifys them as one dataset.
The line number of any dataset varies.

Is there a smart way first getting the maximal line number and then coalesce the text together without left joining by each line number?

Here is something what works but it isn't a smart way to hardcode 40 leftjoins:

```
 SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT id,
          COALESCE(Rtrim(Cast(z1.dfw350_text AS VARCHAR(MAX))), '') + Char(13) + Char(10) + COALESCE(Rtrim(Cast(z2.dfw350_text AS VARCHAR(MAX))), '') + Char(13) + Char(10) + COALESCE(Rtrim(Cast(z3.dfw350_text AS VARCHAR(MAX))), '') + Char(13) + Char(10) + COALESCE(Rtrim(Cast(z4.dfw350_text AS VARCHAR(MAX))), '') + Char(13) + Char(10) + COALESCE(Rtrim(Cast(z5.dfw350_text AS VARCHAR(MAX))), '') + Char(13) + Char(10) + COALESCE(Rtrim(Cast(z6.dfw350_text AS VARCHAR(MAX))), '') + Char(13) + Char(10) + COALESCE(Rtrim(Cast(z7.dfw350_text AS VARCHAR(MAX))), '') .... AS texte
   FROM table1
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT *
      FROM table1
      WHERE linenumb = 2 ) z2 ON table1.id = z2.id
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT *
      FROM table1
      WHERE linenumb = 3 ) z3 ON table1.id = z3.id
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT *
      FROM table1
      WHERE linenumb = 4 ) z4 ON table1.id = z4.id) AS ka
INNER JOIN (
SELECT id,
       linenumb
FROM table2
GROUP BY id,
         linenumb x ON ka.id=x.id
```

**The expected output is a query like this:**

```
ID   | Text
----------------------
342  | Sample Text..
343  | Lorem ipsum
344  | Pellentesque habitant
```

Comment: What is the expected output for the given sample? I see 4 different IDs and no `linenumb=1` for `ID=343`...

Comment: I changed it now. The dataset's got now the same ID including the expected output.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this just based on the two column table you showed us, because a column providing the _ordering_ for the text fragments is lacking.

Comment: you need to understand here that in tsql..a table is a set..and in set there is no relevance to the order of elements...so conceptually rows in a table have no particular order. You say that in table 2 the second line should come first and be matched with second line of first table but how will system know what exactly is `second`..the order i mean..

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your table actually had a third column which provided ordering, you could do a simple aggregation query:

```
ID   | Position | Text
-----|----------|-----------------------
342  | 1        | Sampl
342  | 2        | e Text...
343  | 1        | Lorem ipsum
344  | 1        | Pellentesque habitant

SELECT
    ID,
    STRING_AGG (Text, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Position) Text_Concat
FROM table1
GROUP BY
    ID;
```

[image: screen capture of demo]

### Demo